# NSURL/NSURLRequest is unexpectedly nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to load a PDF into a UIWebView, but when using `loadRequest`, I'm getting the error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional`. My relevant code is below:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.urartuuniversity.com/content_images/pdf-sample.pdf")!

    println(url.fileURL)

    println("The URL is \(url.absoluteURL!)")

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

The second line of code outputs false (unsurprisingly), but the third outputs the correct URL. webView is a connected UIWebView.

I've looked at a few examples of similar errors yet none seemed applicable, especially because the NSURL appears to be working due to the `URL.absoluteURL!` correctly outputting, as did numerous other similar commands.

I've also seen references to RFC 2396, but when looking at W3's documentation, my URL appears to be following these guidelines, but if it doesn't, then please tell me what the format is and how to change the URL (because I will have to literally change thousands more, and this PDF is merely an example PDF I found online).

When looking in the debug section, url is a NSURL and the place holding its value says the URL of the PDF, rather than a memory address, which could contribute partly to some of my problems.

**Edit:** To make my situation even weirder, because I'm using a universal app with a split-view and a table view, when I load an iPad, the PDF loads correctly, but the moment I go back to the master view and click on something, reloading the detail view, the fatal exception is found. If this made no sense, please tell me and I'll try to make it more comprehensible.

Comment: Your url is not nil, so the question title might be a little misleading. Anyway I suggests you to double check if everything is hooked up correctly with your interface builder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on both the title and interface builder, and everything is connected in the interface builder.

Comment: Try `if let webView = webView { webView.loadRequest(request) } else { print("webView is nil") }` just to check if for some reason your webView has gone at the time you try to load the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do not know what is nil. Add more logging, like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.urartuuniversity.com/content_images/pdf-sample.pdf")!
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
println(url)
println(request)
println(webView)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

In this way, by putting your app through its paces and trying to reproduce the crash, you will discover, just *before* the crash, exactly *what* is nil. I'm guessing it's the `webView`, but guessing is not programming — and the problem is that, so far, *you* are just guessing. Don't guess. You have a debugger! Debug!!!

Comment: yeah..i tried the above sample...and its working for me

Comment: After doing that, you were right, the webView was nil, but I deleted and recreated the connection, but it's still not working, plus that doesn't explain how it works the first time on iPad. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say that's a different question. Now that you know _what_ is happening you can start to think about why. You will need to describe your view controller hierarchy and segues, I expect, in your new question...